# Letter of recommendation for grad. school application source

Tags: recommendation-letter

I am applying for admission to the Master's program next fall. However I am in doubt about the source of reference. I have two options:

1. My mentor at a research institute who was pursuing his PhD. when I was a research intern. However, he did not complete his PhD.
2. Research Scientist(PhD) at my current organization where my role is that of a software developer. Therefore the recommendation is based on my work as a developer rather than on my research contributions.

Both are willing to write strong recommendations for me.

Who would be a better source of recommendation?

Comment: Many applications require (or allow) more than one reference.  Is that not your case?

Comment: I need 3 recommendations.  2 professors from my undergraduate institute are recommending me.

Comment: Are you sure you can't include four recommendations? Many application management systems will allow for additional materials. You can ask the graduate school whether they will allow this.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask mentor #1 (with a master's degree) to write a letter to the PhD research scientist #2, and have the latter (#2) submit a letter for your application. Thus, the recommendation letter is received from a prestigious source, is based on current experience of your work habits and character, but can also incorporate quotes/details from the more junior person. This is not an unusual pattern in my experience.

Answer (score -1):

I would use the first person because it is about your work in research. I think that their qualifications matter very little: What really matters is the nature of your work when you were under their supervision.